# Cannot create first react app, events.js:200 throw react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-native

When I started creating my first app using command line `npx create-react-app myapp`, it did not start and when I used `npm start` I get the following error.

The log I encountered after running the command:

```
        Starting the development server...

    events.js:200
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    ←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)←[39m
    ←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)←[39m
    ←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)←[39m
    Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    ←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)←[39m
    ←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)←[39m
    ←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)←[39m {
      errno: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
      code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
      syscall: ←[32m'spawn cmd'←[39m,
      path: ←[32m'cmd'←[39m,
      spawnargs: [ ←[32m'/s'←[39m, ←[32m'/c'←[39m, ←[32m'start'←[39m, ←[32m'""'←[39m, ←[32m'/b'←[39m, ←[32m'"http://localhost:3000/"'←[39m ]
    }
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Believer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-23T23_26_01_725Z-debug.log

    c:\Users\Believer\Documents\React\myapp>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your computer have enough resources to run the program?

Comment: According to this post (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7347), does `npm cache clean --force` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First Remove the node_modules directory and reinstalling again using `npm install`

and then `killall node`

then `npm start`

Most of the time this error occurs when there are more than one app is using the node server

You can also try it by changing the port

Create a **.env** file at your project root and specify the port number there. Like:

```
PORT=3005
```

If that doesn't work either that means you don't have the multiple apps running problem